# Is it possible to use WhatsApp Web without scanning the QR code?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a camera issue in my phone that it is not able to scan the QR code. Is there any other way to use WhatsApp Web without the QR code, like using OTP?

Comment: https://www.timesnownews.com/technology-science/article/login-to-whatsapp-web-without-scanning-qr-code-heres-how/566750

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way is to migrate WhatsApp to a device that does have a relevant camera.

But as the article in the question's first comment mentions, you can emulate such a device and thus use WhatsApp directly in your computer (i.e. run Android in your computer). It'll be slow and unfriendly though.

If it's any consolation, WhatsApp plans to support Desktop computers independently.<sup>[[1]](https://engineering.fb.com/2021/07/14/security/whatsapp-multi-device/)</sup>
Hopefully it'd be unlike Telegram which requires another device to log you in.<sup>[[2]](https://bugs.telegram.org/c/4239)</sup>